# "Criteria" versus "criterion"

Tags: grammar, meaning, grammatical-number

I came across several forums and articles saying that *criteria* is plural and *criterion* is singular. Some gave me the impression that *criterion* is used to denote a set of rules.

What is the correct use of these two words?

Comment: So is it correct to say "There are three criteria to this project?"

Comment: @Mike: 'one criterion', 'three criteria'. 'criteria/on to this..' sounds weird. Use 'criteria for...'. Though your punctuation is probably correct for American writing, from a logical use/mention aspect, you should say: '... "...this project." ?'. That is, the punctuation for the quote, inside the quote and the punctuation for the sentence at large outside the quote.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

According to [Merriam-Webster.com](http://www.m-w.com/dictionary/criterion), *criteria* is indeed plural and *criterion* is singular.  The dictionary definition is "a standard on which a judgement or decision may be made"; it's often used synonymously with "requirement(s)", as in "if you don't meet the criteria you won't be allowed in" or "I have one all-important criterion by which I judge potential plumbing contractors: is their shirt tucked in to their belted pants?"

M-W.com also notes that the use of "criteria" as singular has been gaining ground for a long time (50 years or so) and may be considered acceptable usage by now.

(To which I say, fight the change!  Use "criterion" correctly!)

Comment: For those for whom *criteria* is singular, what is the plural? Criterias? Criteriae? Criterions? :-)

Comment: It's all just "criteria".  One criteria, two criteria.  Just like fish, I guess.

Comment: Like fish?  I thought the plural of fish was fishies.  You know, "Oh, lots of colorful fishies!".

Comment: +1: I will note that of the three answers here so far, Hellion's is the only one that actually answers the OP's question.

Comment: Anyone notice a difference when used in a technical context, such as in code?

Comment: Does this mean that "set of criteria" is erroneous? You can have a "set of criterion" or criteria.

Comment: @Acco No, "a set of criteria" would be correct, because a set, in standard usage, implies more than one member.  (Mathematically, of course, you can have an empty set or a single-member set; but in normal English, a set is taken to be 2 or more items taken together.)

Answer (score 9):

*Criterion* comes from Classical Greek. Its gender is neuter and it belongs to the second declension — like the word *phenomenon*.

Comment: +1 for mentioning phenomenon/a before I had the chance to :-)

Answer (score 2):

I would say that *criteria* is used to denote a set of rules, and that one of those rules would be a *criterion*.

Actually, I wouldn't say that, as a criterion and a rule aren't quite the same thing.  I'd make a GRE-style analogy:  Criteria is to set of rules as criterion is to rule.

Answer (score 0):

> You should not use criteria when you mean criterion for the same
>   reason that you should not use criterion when you mean criteria. These
>   is my only criterions. -George Carlin

Answer (score -1):

In English, a lot of nouns have kept the original ending coming from classical Greek or Latin. Criterion is just one of them. In science you find a lot of words with these queer plural forms, but in fact they follow  the Greek and latin declensions:
Latin:
alga- algae
stimulus -stimuli
bacterium -bacteria
species-speciei (except  that this one is no longer used, it has been replaced by species, due to the fact that in several modern languages "s" means plural.
Greek:
a thesis -2 theses
an analysis -two analyses
 a criterion -two criteria

This means that if you know the singular form in "a" or "us" or "um", you can deduce the plural !!

Comment: No, there is no general rule for producing a plural given a word that ends in this or that: you can only deduce the original plural if you actually know Latin or Greek. For example, **the nominative plural of *species* in Latin was the very same word, *species*; the genitive singular was the *speciei* spelling you erroneously gave.** Similarly, you can only know the Latin plural of an *-us* word if you know its declension, or else you will get their Latin plurals wrong in pairs like *genus/genera, corpus/corpora, apparatus/apparatus*. You might also get *stigma/stigmata* wrong from Greek.