# difference Criterion vs Criterium

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Extending this question: ["Criteria" versus "criterion"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12357/criteria-versus-criterion)

What is the difference between "criterion" (singl, noun) and "criterium" (singl, noun) ?

Comment: A dictionary would have been the single best way to answer this one yourself.

Comment: I think a dictionary could have answered this one.

Comment: I checked LEO and DICT and it is NOT helpful for me (I'm no native english speaker). One page says that "criterium" is used in context of bicycle racing but I don't fully get its meaning in that context.

Comment: @DanFromGermany If the answers below aren't clear, the two words are unrelated in use and simply appear similar because they share a common root - "to judge". One (*criterion*) thus becomes the thing by which we make a judgement, while the other (*criterium*) is a type of cycling competition (and thus gets judged).

Comment: I thought criterium was a special criterion of the bike race. Now it's clear :-)

Comment: The question I linked which has some upvotes and is even protected could have been looked up in a dictionary, too.  98% of all stackexchange questions can be answer with "look in this book the answer is there".

Comment: @DanFromGermany Maybe you're right. But the rules weren't strict back then. The linked question is at least 5 years old. Since the site is more popular now, we need to enforce certain rules to maintain quality.

Comment: For us whose native language is _not_ English, this is a great question. For example, plural: _data_ and singular: _datum_ (from Latin). How can I tell this does _not_ mean plural: _criteria_ and singular: _criterium_? Well, if I know some basic Latin, but my English is not quite strong enough, I _cannot_ tell. Right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Criterion is [something used to help make a judgement or decision](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/criterion)

Criterium is [a bike race](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/criterium)

Answer (score 6):

**tl;dr**: You in general want *criterion, criteria*, because *criterium, criteriums* is a very specialized term.

---

The normal word is *criterion, criteria*, which per [Oxford Dictionaries Online](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/criterion) means “a principle or standard by which something may be judged or decided.”  The specialized U.S. term *criterium, criteriums* is again [per Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/criterium) “a one-day bicycle race on a circuit road course.”

The singular noun corresponding to the plural noun *criteria* is *criterion*.  These are from the Greek, where you see *-ion, -ia* for singular and plural.

The term *criterium* comes to us from French.  It's a kind of bicycle circuit race. Per [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/criterium) it derives from:

> From French *critérium* ‎(“competition”), from Late Latin *criterium*, from Ancient Greek *κριτήριον* ‎(*kritḗrion*).

With further explanation from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Criterium):

> A *criterium*, or *crit*, is a bike race consisting of several laps around a closed circuit, the length of each lap or circuit ranging from about 1 km to 2 km.

Comment: I love your answers, but don't you think this question was "general reference"? :)

Comment: @NVZ Don't worry: I blame Rory. :)  ɴᴏᴛ

Comment: lol - I did vote to close, and I probably should have just put mine as a comment. (actually - if any mod wants to convert it to a comment, that's fine)

Comment: Thank you for posting the only correct answer, which means based on etymological explanations, without which, language makes no sense.